# Improve speed of calculating large raster stack of climate data

Tags: r

I have a large raster stack (4396663296 elements, 13.3 Mb) that contains monthly precipitation data over Alaska and Canada between 1920-2015, downscaled to 2km.  I would like to calculate mean annual precipitation for the observation period (1920-2015), but I'm finding that my code is bogging down `R`.  Is there a faster and more efficient way to execute the following code?

```
library(raster)

# create list of raster files from wd
r <- stack(list.files(pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE))

# create index for month/year
nyears <- rep(1:95, each=12)

# next line bogs down R
rsum <- stackApply(r, indices=nyears, fun=sum)  
ravg <- calc(rsum, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Do I simply need to do this in batches (say, decadal increments)?  Or am I missing something clever?

Data available here: http://ckan.snap.uaf.edu/dataset/historical-monthly-and-derived-precipitation-products-downscaled-from-cru-ts-data-via-the-delta.
Note, this provides monthly data between 1901-2015, however, I have elected to use 1920-2015 in my analysis and only included .tiff files from those years.

Comment: using a parallel process. Raster has the function cluster (`?cluster`) so you can run some tasks in parallel. Otherwise doFuture / furture.apply can help

Comment: You could also try installing R open from Microsoft it uses multi-threaded math libraries (intel mkl) so many computations are much faster - this especially holds true if matrix are involved.

Answer (score 0):

It it probably faster to do

```
ravg <- mean(r) * 12
```

or perhaps

```
ravg <- calc(r, fun=function(x) mean(x) * 12)
```